# Modifying specific column on the lines using a Bash script

Tags: bash

I want to modify my tab-delimited file like as below.

## Original file

```
a001.2[tab]xxx[tab]001[tab]zz
bbb[tab]ddd[tab]293[tab]kkjk
c054.9[tab]ccc[tab]786[tab]qq
```

## Modified file

```
a001[tab]xxx[tab]001[tab]zz
bbb[tab]ddd[tab]293[tab]kkjk
c054[tab]ccc[tab]786[tab]qq
```

I want to remove decimal (ex. a001.2 to a001) at the first column only using bash scripts.
Please let me know how should I do.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `;`s are actually tabs?

Comment: Sorry, HTML tag doesn't work. I fixed to [tab]. Thanks for catching that. :-)

Comment: Does it have to be a shell construct or you are open to `sed`, `awk` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^\t]+)\.[^\t]+(.*)/\1\2/' file.txt
```

If the file is not large, you can use `bash` `while` loop with parameter expansion:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read i j; do echo "${i%%.*}"$'\t'"$j"; done <file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt  
a001.2  xxx 001 zz
bbb     ddd 293 kkjk
c054.9  ccc 786 qq

$ sed -E 's/^([^\t]+)\.[^\t]+(.*)/\1\2/' file.txt
a001    xxx 001 zz
bbb     ddd 293 kkjk
c054    ccc 786 qq

$ while IFS=$'\t' read i j; do echo "${i%%.*}"$'\t'"$j"; done <file.txt
a001    xxx 001 zz
bbb     ddd 293 kkjk
c054    ccc 786 qq
```